# Capybara's visit method returns : NoMethodError: undefined method `to_i' for true:TrueClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, devise, capybara, confirmation

I'm trying to go through the confirmation process :

```
request_url = "/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=azq32soznE1xuSWLjBat"
```

Then when I do :

```
visit request_url
```

It returns :

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_i' for true:TrueClass
```

I thought, originally, that this was Devise, but it doesn't hit any of my debuggers so it never even makes it there. What's even more puzzling was that I made no adjustments to this area of my app, so I'm very confused as to how this suddenly arose.

Any ideas on how to debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is the confirmation token doesn't exist. Look at the code surrounding the error, you have something that is saying

```
my_variable = true
my_variable.to_i
```

You're calling `.to_i` somewhere on a boolean, which is no good.

Comment: I just checked my automated test history, and this started failing when I upgraded devise. But since I've restored devise to its original state. So whatever caused this bug.. hasn't gone away despite me restoring it to its original state. In regards to the `.to_i`, I have no idea *what* is calling that since its all handled exclusively through Devise.

Comment: And the error gives you no more context in your code? Line number, file name, etc?

Comment: Ugh I wish! This is just my tests. The actual app itself works fine. Maybe something got cached in the test environment? Hmm.. maybe when I upgraded Devise it did something with the migrations.

Comment: Ha that was it. Just solved it by resetting the db. ;) Thanks for helping me think out loud.